# CodePipeline buildspec and multiple build actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

A simple buildspec like:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - (cd lambda/src; npm install)
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file lambda/sam.yml --s3-bucket skynet-lambda --output-template-file SkynetLambdaPackaged.yml

artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - SkynetLambdaPackaged.yml
```

Works fine when I have one action in my build stage. But what if I want to have more build actions for example: I want to build my api server and frontend files in parallel. How do I model this?

**UPDATE**

In CodePipeline I can create actions that run in parallel like below, how is this modeled in buildspec? Or isit impossible?

[image]

Comment: That's not true anymore please get the latest updates about AWS CodeBuild, where you can add multiple Build stages in your AWS CodePipeline [create-multiple-builds-from-the-same-source-using-different-aws-codebuild-build-specification-files](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/create-multiple-builds-from-the-same-source-using-different-aws-codebuild-build-specification-files/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two different CodeBuild projects from the same source as two separate *parallel* actions in your CodePipeline.

For this to happen, you can use two `buildspec` files in your source.

e.g.

*buildspec-frontend.yml*

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - (cd frontend/src; npm run build)
      - aws s3 sync frontend/dist s3://<insert s3 bucket url here>/ --delete
```

*buildspec-backend.yml*

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - (cd lambda/src; npm install)
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file lambda/sam.yml --s3-bucket skynet-lambda --output-template-file SkynetLambdaPackaged.yml
```

Then, create a frontend CodeBuild project that uses the frontend buildspec. Repeat for the backend.

Then, when you go to your *Build* stage in your CodePipeline, use the two CodeBuild projects as parallel actions.

---

*Update: The information below is now irrelevant since I misunderstood the question.*

If your frontend can be deployed to s3, just add its deployment commands where you put your api deployment commands.

e.g.

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - (cd lambda/src; npm install)
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file lambda/sam.yml --s3-bucket skynet-lambda --output-template-file SkynetLambdaPackaged.yml
      - (cd frontend/src; npm run build)
      - aws s3 sync frontend/dist s3://<insert s3 bucket url here>/ --delete
```

If your frontend is not on s3, just replace those lines with your own frontend deployment commands.

CodeBuild executes those commands in sequence. If you really need to run them in parallel, there are many ways to do it.

My preference is to put the commands in a `Makefile` and call them from your `buildspec.yml` (e.g. `make --jobs 2 backend frontend`).

Comment: But this will run commands sequentially correct? I think its better to do it as separate actions so its run in parallel?

Comment: Each phase in the buildspec is ran sequentially not in parallel. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/view-build-details.html#view-build-details-phases

Comment: @JiewMeng I know CodePipeline stages can have parallel actions. I don't think CodeBuild supports that though. Can you point to some docs that indicate that? That will be useful for me as well.

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions.html. The image of actions in parallel is in the OP's update

Comment: I see where the confusion is. As I mentioned, CodePipeline can have parallel actions. CodePipeline does NOT use `buildspec.yml`. CodeBuild does.

CodeBuild executes buildspec phases in sequence.

Comment: How do you specify different yml files per build? I only have the option to choose the buildspec.yml file.

Comment: @ChrisO Example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/create-multiple-builds-from-the-same-source-using-different-aws-codebuild-build-specification-files

Answer (score -4):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMkTn.png)
From my understanding, if you just have one source, you cannot have two buildspec file because you can only name that file as buildspec. Maybe you can try "Insert build commands" option

Comment: This is not true anymore and you can name the buildspec file to your liking.