# best approach to run AWS CodeBuild steps in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm new to CodeBuild and have built a CodeBuild project that builds a set of AMIs.

It takes a long time to run.  In other build systems like circleci and concourse I've used features that allow build steps to run in separate docker containers in parallel and the build system waits for them all to finish and then proceeds to the next step.

Does CodeBuild support something like this?  I don't see that it does...

If it doesn't, what is the best approach?  Is this a use case for CodePipeline?

I could also pass in each `ami` as a parameter to the build and run `n` copies of the build simultaneously (trigger with a script that launches one build per ami).

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: As I mentioned in my AWS forum reply in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=309294, CodeBuild doesn't have native support for parallel builds. You may either split the task up into smaller builds to use multiple input output feature or rely on docker-compose to run containers in parallel as part of your build.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done now using [Batch Build](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/batch-build.html). Matrix can be another useful feature from the same set.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the existing answer in StackOverflow that might help you achieve the parallelism.

[CodePipeline buildspec and multiple build actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020587/codepipeline-buildspec-and-multiple-build-actions)